# Left menu like wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a javascript library (better if can be done usiny jquery) to replicate more or less the functionality of the left menubar of wordpress once you are logged.

This menus has images with names, you can expand/collapse, if you hover you can see the options in a new extended window, if you click on it the menu expand with the same previously show options, ...

I've found some libraries/jquery plugins but they are not too close ...

I'm not tied to find a free open option, it can be a commercial one.

Maye it can be done with jquery collapse, but well, if it already exists, better ...

thanks,

[image: See the attached image.]

Comment: There's probably no drop-in solution that covers the JS, CSS and PHP that makes the result. But if you want the exact same thing, why don't you use the exact same thing? It's Free Software, after all. https://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/

Comment: interesting, I didn't know about it, I'll have a look. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basic javascript and css will do the job, the menu is an ul and each menu-item is a li with another ul inside of it, which has display:none; in css. When you click it just use javascript to show it. For the hover just add an event listener to hover on each li-element and either show/hide the ul or append it.

Or am I missing something you're after?

Comment: Well, I'm not a javascript/jquery guru, my job is totally different but I have to integrate something similar :-)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

[Look at this demo](http://jsbin.com/irunik/edit#javascript,html,live)

```
$('ul#tabs li').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('ul').hide().stop().animate({height: 'toggle'});
}, function(){
  $(this).find('ul').stop().animate({height: 'toggle'});
});
```

Works also with JS disabled.

Comment: not too bad :-) The difference with wordpress is that if you hover the menu, the options are visible on the right (like yours), but if you click on the menu, the options appear below, and they are like an accordion, only one menu can show their submenu at once. thanks